# Android VPNService - how do I bring up the 'system-managed dialog' from my activity?

Tags: android, service, android-activity, system, vpn

According to [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/VpnService.html) tutorial the only way to disconnect the vpn service is to use the 'system-managed dialog'. This can be done manually by dragging down the notification bar and selecting it from there, however this is not a good solution for my problem.

I need to be able to bring this dialog up from within my app when a 'disconnect' button is pressed, however I can't find any documentation on how to do this.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now the only public and recommended way to disconnect is unfortunately just through the notification. The functions for disconnecting or even bringing up the dialog are otherwise hidden unfortunately.

Of course, that doesn't necessarily mean that they can't be accessed, but that way lies much pain. I haven't tried this in this specific case, but I have done this in the past, way back, with the music player to find out what was playing (for audio scrobbling). So if you absolutely must find a way to do this, no matter how hacky, then you could try this, but keep in mind that 'ere be dragons - this involves accessing a private API that you are not supposed to. That API could change on a whim between any two given builds of android (not just platform versions either), because it is supposed to be private and internal. You would need to make your code very resilient to failure here, and frankly it'll never be anything more than hacky and a PITA.

Right, all that said, [see line 171 in this](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Settings/+/e7565f3c48e6c90e65d9c15e33d20673a187c156/src/com/android/settings/vpn/AuthenticationActor.java)

That's what you want to do. Except you can't see the things you need, right? So you need [this AIDL for the service](http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/donut/frameworks/base/vpn/java/android/net/vpn/IVpnService.aidl) (and possibly a bit of reflection too, I forget - haven't done this in a long time).

[This blog post](http://blog.codetastrophe.com/2008/12/accessing-hidden-system-service-apis-in.html) describes something similar, though not in much detail. It's hard to find things talking about, since it is an incredibly discouraged practice.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I have a problem though when trying to use reflection to access this class, it keeps giving me classNotFoundException for com.android.settings.vpn.AuthenticationActor Could you maybe help explain why?

Comment: Well I wasn't suggesting you access AuthenticationActor - I was suggesting you'd need to do the same thing it does in that block. In order to do that you need to be able to connect to the same service, for which you would need the AIDL. This will only work if the service is accessible and just hidden though. If it is outright protected from access it won't. I recall with the music service they had left it unprotected but hidden it.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is fine just to close tun descript and let the Service end. This will effectlivy end the VPN (but the app in question will still hold the permission to open a VPN again). The notification (key symbol) will also go away. If you are trying the VPNService of another app that might be tougher. Perhaps you should ask the author of that app for an API.